Identical id and name values when duplicating ACF blocks on page editor
I have created several ACF field groups and I am using them as blocks on the page editor so the user can enter whatever content they want. I've made many websites in this style and I have never come across this issue before.
When a block is duplicated in the page editor, the ID and name values of the duplicate input fields are identical to the original and this is obviously causing problems.
Does anybody know any fixes for this? Is it something to do with my database?
Thanks in advance.

In 6.3.0, ACF added the functionality of saving data in blocks to the page's meta data (release notes), which can be a problem if you've multiple of the same block on one page. Is the data being saved to the block, or the post meta?

I used the ACF plug-in to create all my blocks which then creates its own JSON. I have just noticed something a little bit strange though. The issue persists, however, when I change the data in the original BEFORE duplicating it, it duplicates as it should. Is there anyway to sort of refresh the JSON data in the current blocks?
